# error: expression must have struct or union type in c when passing struct as param in function

Tags: c

I have such a struct

```
struct Request
{
    char command[COMMAND_LENGHT];
    char firstSetName[SET_NAME_LENGTH];
    char secondSetName[SET_NAME_LENGTH];
    char resultSetName[SET_NAME_LENGTH];
    int input[sizeof(int) * 4];
};
```

and I have such a method

```
int parseToReadRequest(char * command, struct Request ** request)
{
    printf("Command is : %s\n", command);

    *request.firstSetName = "firs";

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I understood when you need to pass a struct as a param you need to mark it with `**`

but anyway when I try to assign a struct value `firstSetName` I get an error

> Expression must have struct or union type

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I get such error

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this expression:

```
*request.firstSetName = "firs";
```

The member access operator `.` has the highest precedence, so it assumes that `request` is a `struct` or `union` type.  However it is not.  It is a pointer-to-pointer-to struct.

If your intent is to modify an instance of a `struct`, you don't need a double pointer.  Just a single will do:

```
int parseToReadRequest(char * command, struct Request *request)
```

Then, you would need to either put parenthesis around `*request` to ensure the pointer is first dereferenced before using `.`:

```
(*request).firstSetName = "firs";
```

Or you can use the pointer-to-member operator `->` which is cleaner:

```
request->firstSetName = "firs";
```

However there is another issue here.  You're attempting to assign a value to an array.  An array can't be assigned to directly.  What you want instead is to use the `strcpy` function which is used to copy strings:

```
strcpy(request->firstSetName, "firs");
```

Comment: Edited my question. How do you suppose I get such an error?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the structure by reference, ie. pass the pointer to it. You need to pass a double pointer only if you need to modify the pointer itself (for example dynamically allocate a structure inside the function).

The function should be: `int parseToReadRequest(char * command, struct Request * request)`

And inside the function you should access the structure fields like this: `request->firstSetName`